# Adobe Encore and DVD Subpictures inconsistency

Tags: encore

Good evening,

What do I need to do in order to make DVD subpictures be rendered exactly as I designed it in Adobe Encore or in Adobe Photoshop?

Please, take a look at the pictures listed below (because I don't have permissions to post links and pictures are a little big):

[image: - Image #1]

This is what I see while editing the menu template in Adobe Photoshop. I've toggled the visibility of subpictures layers so they can be seen, because Encore guidelines says they must be hidden to work properly.

[image: - Images #2]
 [image: - Images #3]

These picture show what I see in Adobe Encore Project Preview. As you can see, the subpictures work fine, just as expected.

[image: - Images #4]
 [image: - Images #5]

These pictures show what I see in the Video Player (VLC in this case). When hovering the action buttons, which trigger the subpictures, the one associated to to the number "2" is misaligned while the one associated to the number "3" seems to be clipped.

Initially I designed the subpictures as a normal Text Layer. Now I see it was a terrible workaround but the last two pictures I took after re-render the project whith these layers rasterized, and the problem continues.

This is all I need to finish this gift.

Note: I would like to add the proper tags (dvd, photoshop and, maybe, subpictures) but I'm not allowed to do it too. <_<

Comment: Just to clarify, you are talking about the underlines on the number correct?  It took a little bit to spot the differences between the frames.

Comment: Exactly! These subpictures are driving me crazy!